# Can't upload a document to my mongoDB server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am studying on my own node.js and I am following codewithmosh website.
The thing is, is that I try to upload a new object to my mongo database using compass.
I have the following code (see screenshots for outputs) and there is no error and on mosh'es tutorial everything is working great.

The problem I have is that my server isn't being updated with the new document.
Any idea what I am missing?

I refreshed the compass a few times and nothing changes.

[image]

[image]

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/playground', { useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true}).then(() =>
    console.log('connected to MongoDB')
).catch((err) => console / log('Could not connect to MongoDB', err));


const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    author:String,
    tags: [String],
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    isPublished: Boolean
})

const Course = mongoose.model('Course', courseSchema);
async function createCourse () {
    const course = new Course ({
        name: 'node.js Course',
        author: 'Daniel',
        tags: ['node', 'backend'],
        isPublished: true,

    });
    const result = await course.save();
    console.log(result);
}

createCourse();
```

Comment: It is working perfectly you just need to refresh the compass.

Comment: I refreshed a few times and nothing changes

Comment: Give this a try: check the amount of documents without compass `console.log(await Course.count({}));`

Comment: it says 23...probably me upload it a lot of times :) so what wrong with compass? I want a UI so I could see whats happening

Comment: Good to know that code is working. Hard to say whats wrong with your compass...

Comment: check your connected server host and port in compass, both connection string should be same.

Comment: OK I figure out the problem.
Now I have another issue:
 MongoDB MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-00.czblp.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoError: bad auth Authentication failed

Comment: OK I fixed the previous issue.
Now WTH is this?
ngoClient constructor.
Could not connect to MongoDB null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I figure it out.
There was a bad configuration in my compass.
I had to go to setup a connection